# python can we override a method by inheriting 2 class

Tags: python

```
class A(object):

    def print_some(self):
        print 'a'

class B(object):

    def print_some(self):
        print 'b'

class C(A, B):
    pass

c = C()
print c.print_some()
'a'
```

What i expect of the output is 'b'. The reason i want to do this is because i want to override some method, let's say `form_valid` from `CreateView` in django, simply by inheriting a class i write containing custom `form_valid`, or there are better approaches?

Comment: You are describing the behavior of normal inheritance. The correct approach is to make your custom class a subclass of `CreateView`

Answer (score 4):

class `A` is first (left) in the `class C(A, B)` instruction, so you are getting the `print_some` method from it (`A` class). Read [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Answer (score 0):

From your question I expect you can change the inheritance of B and C, can't you? So why don't you build up the inheritance like

```
A <- B <- C
```

Or in code:

```
class A(object):
    ....

class B(A):
    ...

class C(B):
    ...
```

This should give you the desired output.